# How to fake a user-agent on Jquery Mobile Ajax requests in iOS fullscreen mode (using apple-mobile-web-app-capable)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm pulling my hair out with this one...

My app is running on `jquery-mobile (1.1.1)`, `jquery (1.7.2)` and `requireJS` on the front end. Running the app in Mobile Safari on (ipad1+3, iOS3+5) works fine, but if I open the app through the home screen icon using

```
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

all my Jquery Mobile AJAX requests to load new pages or go back/forth between pages fail. Instead the **error loading page** message briefly blinks before the linked to page simply gets freshly loaded, restarting my app.

I have been sitting on this for two days now and have tried all of the following:

`manifest` (I'm actually not using a manifest, just tried to see whether it helped)

- [add network resources](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajax-fail-in-mobile-app) > didn't help

`requireJS`

- remove requireJS completely from my app > still doesn't work
- [cache busting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315088/prevent-requirejs-from-caching-required-scripts) > didn't help

`offline`

- [set isLocal](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1194)

But I'm still stuck with pages not being loaded and the navigation breaking.

The one cause that made sense to me was [in this blog post](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2011/05/29/Gotcha-iPad-versus-ASPNET.aspx), which argued that Safari uses a different HTTP User-Agent string in fullscreen mode vs Mobile Safari. The strings passed in fullscreen seem unrecognizable resulting in only basic browser settings being expected (such as no javascript support).

The workaround (`for ASP.net`) posted is faking the user-agent like so:

```
 protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if (Request.UserAgent != null && Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("AppleWebKit", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1) {
        this.ClientTarget = "uplevel";
        }
      }
```

**Question:**
How would I include a fix like this (~ faking the user agent) in Javascript/Jquery when iOS fullscreen mode is active (is this detectable at all)? Also I'm curious whether there are any caveats to this approach? Seems wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is the problem with user-agent then it is simply impossible to solve with javascript. The user-agent cannot be changed through a javascript. It is sent to the server by the application (web browser) before a javascript is downloaded. trying any trick with javascript does not work either since it is specified in the XMLHttpRequest standard that a request must be immediately terminated if the script is trying to change any of these headers ( [JQuery Ajax Request: Change User-Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771878/jquery-ajax-request-change-user-agent) ):

```
Accept-Charset
Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Request-Method
Connection
Content-Length
Cookie
Cookie2
Content-Transfer-Encoding
Date
Expect
Host
Keep-Alive
Origin
Referer
TE
Trailer
Transfer-Encoding
Upgrade
User-Agent
Via
```

My guess is that this is for security reason.

Alternative, detect the user-agent on of the request on server-side and return code that work for that specific user-agent but, of course, no one wants to do more work.

Are you sure if the user-agent is really different? I cannot think of why your own code would not work if the user-agent is different without you knowing it. The only reason may be in the third party javascript library you use.

Comment: Ok. I was afraid there was no easy solution. Let's see where to get started on the server side... Thanks so far!