# How to add additional information in User-agent in jQuery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, user-agent, stackexchange-api

I read about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127522/how-to-add-a-value-to-user-agent-header-in-a-ajax-request) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771878/jquery-ajax-request-change-user-agent), but still I couldn't figure out how to do it in jQuery `ajax`. I tried the code from one of the answers of the questions I linked, but it discarded the user agent override:

```js
$.ajax({ 
    url: "http://blablabla.com/",
    dataType:'html', 
    beforeSend: function (req) {
        req.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/69916/vikas');
    },
    error: function() { alert("No data found");},
    success: parseResult
});
```

My current User-agent string that is being sent is this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.40 Safari/537.36 Edg/92.0.902.9
```

And I want to add my other SE profile URL too, in this which is `https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/69916/vikas`

I want to do this because it has been suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/446/1016161) in case you're involved in chatbots.

> A simple example about how to put additional information, i.e., my profile URL in existing User-agent and send it using ajax to any api, would help.

Comment: 1. Do not assume posts are closed "without reason", it only serves to alienate people. 2. What did you not figure out from the Q&A on changing user-agent with jQuery?

Comment: @OlegValter they talked about replacing the user-agent string with custom one, whereas I'm interested in appending some extra string to existing user-agent string.

Comment: @OlegValter that's the problem. Earlier I thought it's just replacing and not appending, but when I cross checked my console, it says you're not allowed to change it

Comment: ah, your actual problem is the "unable to set an unsafe header" right? Well, that's a bit complicated. The explanation might take a while but in the meantime, you can use the native `fetch` (set the UA to whatever): `(async () => { const res = await fetch(location.href, { method: "GET", headers: { "User-Agent": navigator.userAgent } }); console.log(res); })();`

Comment: continuing on: the problem with setting the header with jQuery is browser-specific (in particular to those using Chromium - Chrome, Edge at least). When the `User-Agent` header was removed from the list of forbidden headers, the paths diverged - it seems like  Chromium-based ones still thinks it is an unsafe header, while Firefox has no problems with it. Since jQuery uses `XMLHttpRequest` under the hood, you won't be able to override in those browsers (at least now). As for the MSE post of Jeff, I think they did not even think of someone requesting from JS back then, it was 2009 after all

Comment: oh, I also forgot to add - be careful as I think Chromium-based ones will silently override the UA back to the original one while FF and others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery uses [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to send the request and is therefore subject to the same limitations and issues it has. In particular, when you call the [`setRequestHeader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader) or provide a `headers` configuration option, a corresponding XMLHttpRequest method is used to set the headers.

This is what jQuery does [under the hood](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/ajax/xhr.js#L55) in case of the configuration object:

```js
// Set headers
for ( i in headers ) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader( i, headers[ i ] );
}
```

As you might know, step 5 of the algorithm from [the spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-setrequestheader()-method) of the `setRequestHeader` method says that it should return if the header is in the "forbidden headers" list:

> 5. If name is a forbidden header name, then return.

This is important as the `User-Agent` header used to be in that list (the [draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-XMLHttpRequest2-20080930/#setrequestheader) that made it forbidden is the one from September 2008). This is no longer the case (see the [issue #37](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/37) on the Fetch repo), however, Chromium-based browsers (meaning you are out of luck with at least Chrome and Edge) will either silently drop it (in case of the Fetch API or throw an error:

> Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"

See the following note from the MDN reference:

> The User-Agent header is no longer forbidden, as per spec — see forbidden header name list (this was implemented in Firefox 43) — it can now be set in a Fetch Headers object, or via XHR setRequestHeader().  However, Chrome will silently drop the header from Fetch requests (see Chromium bug 571722).

MDN refers to the bug [571722](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=571722) which is considered to be worked on, so things are likely to change in the near future.