# how do I authenticate to a Jazz server using pure Javascript?

Tags: authentication, oauth, dojo, user-agent, jazz

I am trying to authenticate to the Jazz server using pure Javascript. I am supposed to be able to do a GET on`https://myserver:9444/qm/authenticated/j_security_check?j_username=foo&j_password=bar` . (same behavior on a POST as well)

This works fine in Ff plugin Poster - if I provide a dummy user-agent header. However, in the JS code I am writing (using dojo.xhrGet), I am getting a 400 - bad request, mostly because the heager is saying Chrome, with a response HTML stating - `You have followed a direct link to log in to a Jazz server.  This page has been presented to ensure that a malicious website cannot use cleverly crafted content to circumvent security. If you would like to log in to the server, please use the link below.`

The problem I have hit is - I am unable to override the user-agent header in teh dojo.xhrGet since it s a protected header and you get a `Refused to set unsafe header "user-agent` if you try to override it with some value like "api".

How do I get around this catch 22?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the `User-Agent` header for `XMLHttpRequest`. See this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771878/jquery-ajax-request-change-user-agent).

If you want to authenticate to a Jazz server, you should use `dojo.xhrPost` to send a HTTP POST request to the form authentication url.

```
dojo.xhrPost({
   url: '/qm/authenticated/j_security_check',
   data: {
     j_username: 'foo',
     j_password: 'bar'
   }
})
```

Comment: POST does not work either get the same HTML document back which says `You have followed a direct link to log in to a Jazz server. This page has been presented to ensure that a malicious website cannot use cleverly crafted content to circumvent security. If you would like to log in to the server, please use the link below.`