# How to enable Google Storage gzip during AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-cloud-storage

I'm accessing JSON files stored in a bucket on Google Storage directly using an AJAX request. However to optimize the communication I want to enable gzip encoding.

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/performance) say I have to send an Accept-Encoding header and an altered User-Agent (containing gzip). Accept-Encoding is no problem, however altering your User-Agent is not possible, the [w3c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5862744/1535656) even specifies so.

How can I still enable gzipping while doing these request?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to download those objects or access their metadata /list them/etc?

Comment: Doesn't your user agent already contain gzip? All modern browsers should.

Comment: jterrace, browsers' user agent strings don't generally include "gzip" -- you might be thinking of the accept-encoding header which pretty much always has gzip listed nowadays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to download your files with gzip encoding, they need to be stored in Google Cloud Storage with that encoding already applied, as well as with the appropriate metadata (Content-Encoding: gzip and proper content type, in this case Content-Type: application/json). If you subsequently request these objects with the Accept-Encoding: gzip request header, GCS will serve them with gzip encoding.

*Edited to add:* "gzip" in the user agent string is no longer required (but doesn't hurt either) -- I've requested that the docs be updated accordingly.

Comment: The docs seemed to imply that they'll apply gzip compression for you, I'll experiment with gzipping the files myselves. Hopefully they update the docs soon!