# jquery - get ajax response and store in variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I want to store the data received from http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/itemInfo/?video_id=Vd85aPZ-QAE&ac=www&t=grp into a variable and access info.h.. i tried this

```
$.ajax({
          async: false,
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/itemInfo/?video_id=Vd85aPZ-QAE&ac=www&t=grp",
          dataType: "json",
          success : function(info) {
                        xml = info.h;
                alert(xml); // WORKS
                    }
        });
```

but no success..

```
infoRehashCallback=function(){4==h.readyState&&("$$$ERROR$$$"==h.responseText?pushItemError():500==h.status?(error_count+=1,4<error_count&&pushItemMaintenance()):(eval(h.responseText),checkInfo()))};infoRehash=function(){var a=new Date;h=createRequestObject();a="http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/itemInfo/?video_id="+video_id+"&ac=www&t=grp&r="+a.getTime();h.onreadystatechange=infoRehashCallback;h.open("GET",a,!0);hs(h);h.send(null)};
startInfoRehash=function(a){video_id=a;infoRehash();interval=window.setInterval("infoRehash()",1E3*interval_diff)};
```

i got this code from the website's javascript

Comment: why you wanto store it in variable?

Answer (score 0):

make a function like this:

```
$.ajax({
          async: false,
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/itemInfo/?video_id=Vd85aPZ-QAE&ac=www&t=grp",
          dataType: "json",
          success : function(info) {
                        ShowAlert(info.h);

                    }
        });

function ShowAlert(a)
{
   alert(a);
// do whatever want to with the result
}
```

Comment: still no alert generated

Comment: is it coming in success funtion?

Comment: the json response is invalid.. but i need a workaround for it.. this is the response info = { "title" : "Hello - Lionel Richie", "image" : "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Vd85aPZ-QAE/default.jpg", "length" : "4", "status" : "serving", "progress_speed" : "", "progress" : "", "ads" : "", "pf" : "", "h" : "f54ed003ec1b3b95be03a68dbcc5cba6", "px" : "" };

Comment: plz can u help me.. any way to remove that "info =" part to make the json valid ?

Comment: use replace like this: info.replace("info =","");

Comment: thnk you.. and is there a way to add requestheader and user agent to the request ?

Comment: here is what you want:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771878/jquery-ajax-request-change-user-agent

Comment: and this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093053/add-header-in-ajax-request-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I got the following response which is not valid json:

```
info = {"status" : "serving", "h" : "-"};
```

Should be:

```
{"status" : "serving", "h" : "-"}
```

Comment: nop it throws a parsing error no way to process the response.

Comment: can we parse it from the curly braces and leave the "info = " ?