# HTTP Post in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, http-post

I am trying to return an access token for the youtube API but do not know how to format this POST in JQuery

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 184
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: google-oauth-playground
client_secret=************&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=1%2FPHiWsKPQXQJCNKBbTPgiR0QHugKlXp8Pd2cRlohjK80hAConmTyV5XVmg2HfO4Ag&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: This is my code so far

```
 jQuery.ajax({
url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token/",
type: "post",
data: {
  grant_type: "refresh_token",
  refresh_token: 'token here',
  client_id: 'id here',
  client_secret: 'secret here',
  access_type: 'offline',

},
success: function(response){
  console.log(response)
}
})

};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771878/jquery-ajax-request-change-user-agent + https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ should be enough for you to use as a reference. Have you any current attempted code to show on here?

Comment: @G0dsquad added edit of my code so far, thanks for reply

Comment: you need to post the parameters not just tack them on the end of the request that's for http get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use AJAX for that. In my opinion [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is the best method but you can even use the [`.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method.

Using `.ajax()`

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Using `.post()`

```
$.post( "test.php", { 'choices[]': [ "Jon", "Susan" ] } );
```

For both cases you have to set your user-agent with this (see [`.ajaxSetup()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("User-Agent","google-oauth-playground");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing a ?

```
/v4/token?client_secret=*******
```