# Convert PHP code to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to convert the following PHP code into JavaScript.

```
<body>
<?php

$opts = array('http'=>array('method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"User-agent: CUSTOM_USER_AGENT\r\n"));

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$file = file_get_contents("http://example.com/file1", false, $context);
    ///open http://example.com/file1 with CUSTOM_USER_AGENT

$pattern = "/^Location:\s*(.*)$/i";

$location_headers = preg_grep($pattern, $http_response_header);
    //find url where this redirects to

echo $location_headers
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. In this case please add effort, at least expected behaviour and the missing semicolon

Comment: Try adding some more description to your question..!

Comment: Thats all i simply want to convert this php code to javascript.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking us to write code from scratch. Please at least attempt the conversion for yourself, then ask for help with the parts that aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rewrite this in JavaScript unless you mean *node.js*

JavaScript cannot access files from another origin unless CORS is enabled.

Also AJAX cannot change the user agent:

[JQuery Ajax Request: Change User-Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771878/jquery-ajax-request-change-user-agent)

Lastly what file are you looking at? It looks like you are searching for a location header statement - that would not even be visible in an Ajax result