# navigator.userAgent vs ajax user-agent header

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, user-agent

I tried the following code (code is from [here](https://gist.github.com/thorsten/148812e9cc4fb6a19215ce22afd4e5a8)) which can change the value of `navigator.userAgent` in browsers, and it works fine! after running this code, when I check the value of `navigator.userAgent`, it is changed to the new value. but then when I send a post request with `ajax`, the `user-agent` header which is automatically sent with my request, has not changed and is the actual user agent of the browser. why the user agent has not changed for ajax request?

```
function setUserAgent(window, userAgent) {
// Works on Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE9+
if (navigator.__defineGetter__) {
    navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function () {
        return userAgent;
    });
} else if (Object.defineProperty) {
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', {
        get: function () {
            return userAgent;
        }
    });
}
// Works on Safari
if (window.navigator.userAgent !== userAgent) {
    var userAgentProp = {
        get: function () {
            return userAgent;
        }
    };
    try {
        Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'userAgent', userAgentProp);
    } catch (e) {
        window.navigator = Object.create(navigator, {
            userAgent: userAgentProp
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery Ajax Request: Change User-Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771878/jquery-ajax-request-change-user-agent)

Comment: What makes you think that AJAX requests use `window.navigator` as its source? As of 2015 it is no longer a forbidden header, which means that you _should_ be able to set it using [`setRequestHeader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader), but Chrome still [silently drops it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name).

Comment: @Ivar thanks for your explanation. setting custom user-agent header does not work in any browser. tested on chrome (as you said), safari and edge

Comment: @Ivar so there is no practical way to change the ajax user agent header?!

Comment: Definitely not for Chrome. The same seems to apply for Edge (Edge is also based on Chromium). It does seem to work in Firefox.